# escape problem in django templates

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, rendering

Let's say that I have this string:

```
s = '<p>Hello!</p>'
```

When I pass this variable to a template, I want it to be rendered as raw html. Looking at the docs I see that I can either use the safe filter:

```
{{s|safe}}
```

or disable autoescape:

```
{%autoescape off}
{{s}}
{%endautoescape%}
```

or inside the python code declare it safe:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
s = mark_safe(s)
```

None of these options are working for me. Whatever I do, the string is displayed as:

```
<p>Hello!</p>
```

I must be missing something, just couldn't figure out what. Is there some security setting somewhere that disallows escaping?

EDIT: Bizarre, the problem seems to be gone after I have restarted the computer.

Comment: "Whatever I do, the string is displayed as: <p>Hello!</p>" - so what's the problem?  Isn't that "raw HTML", which is what you said you want?

Comment: I don't want a <p> displayed, I want to have a paragraph.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/releases/1.0-porting-guide/#learn-to-love-autoescaping

Comment: If it disappeared by restarting your computer, most probably it was a) browser cache or b) you were running wrong version of Django (for example, old path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much covered it, those are indeed all the ways to disable autoescaping.

Are you sure the value you are talking about is actually `s = '<p>Hello!</p>'`?

My hunch is that you have additional escaping somewhere in that string...

Comment: I have even tried this hello string. Actually I have the same issue with all the strings I pass to the templates or send as an e-mail.

Comment: +1 If turning off autoescape isn't working, then the string must be getting passed through something earlier on that escapes the HTML.

Answer (score 10):

I think you should write as follows

```
{{s|escape|safe}}
```

it is ok for me

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life and hours of digging through google

Comment: Interestingly, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) suggests that you put `escape` after `safe`, the variable will print as is. However, that is not the behavior I am seeing.
`{{ var|safe|escape }}` renders the html.
`{{ var|escape|safe }}` renders the variable text as-is.

Answer (score -4):

Look at the HTML source code, is it escaped!??? I don't think so. It should be printing letter by letter, just like this:

```
<
p
>
H
E
L
L
O
<
/
>
```